# Perl IIS7.5 502 error Bad gateway

Tags: perl, iis, iis-7.5, mod-perl

I'm trying to run perl files using IIS 7.5

I followed this tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/50479/how-to-install-perl-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/   and I even installed the perl handler I can notice the perl package manager on each .pl file I also added Strawberry perl inside the handler Mapping `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "%s" %s`

and request path `*pl`

But whever I run that using the webbbroswer I keep receiving the 502 Bad gateway error

did the same for the cgi

WHat I'm missing?

Any help is much appreicated

Comment: Did you enable CGI on IIS?

Comment: @pepo yes :( I did , I also tried to point the CGI to both .exe and the .dll ...nothing changed

Comment: does your perl script work in command line? I have only worked with activestate perl and I did not have any problems with it. You could try that maybe but it should not matter what perl you are using.

Comment: @pepo I created a little hellow world perl script and it seems to work perfectly when I run it ....but thanks for your advice I will check ...or it's also possible that the script I am trying to make work isn't properly written